# Need help understanding dll registration in iInstall shield

Tags: dll, installshield

Using Installshield 2013 Professional, and need help understanding how it registers dll's, ocx's, etc. in my Basic MSI project.  I know that some of them are self registering, but I also know that marking a component as self registering violates best practices.

Therefore, I don't quite understand what I need to do.  Should I just include the component leaving the self register box unchecked?  Does the COM Extract at build setting have something to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Brian,
          Com extract at build time is best practice option. It will extract registry data at build time and same you can see in different tables of MSI, appid, progid etc...

Comment: So if I leave COM extract at build set to No and do not check the self register box, I'm assuming the dll will not be registered - correct?  Also, some dlls in the project do not have the Extract COM data for key file link active when right clicking on files in component view.  Does that mean that the dll does not need to be registered?